# Can a namespace difference between implementations be generalized/abstracted/refactored?

Tags: .net, generics, refactoring, performance, theory

Below are three implementation of the interface. The only difference between implementation `1` and implementation `2` is the namespace containing the `ItemWrapper`. Can this be refactored using generalization or something else perhaps?

```
interface IItemProvider {
    object GetItem(Item item);
}

//1
class SomeNamespaceProvider : IItemProvider {
    object GetItem(Item item) {
        return SomeNamespace.ItemWrapper.GetItem(item);
    }
}

//2
class OtherNamespaceProvider : IItemProvider {
    object GetItem(Item item) {
        return OtherNamespace.ItemWrapper.GetItem(item);
    }
}

//3
class TotallyDifferentProvider : IItemProvider {
    object GetItem(Item item) {
        return DifferentItemRetriever(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I understand that you have **static methods** in classes `SomeNamespace.ItemWrapper` and `OtherNamespace.ItemWrapper` and they don't implement `IItemProvider` interface. You want to turn those static methods to instance methods and you don't know how to do it.

If classes `SomeNamespace.ItemWrapper` and `OtherNamespace.ItemWrapper` aren't static you could implement `IItemProvider` explicitly:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class ItemWrapper: IItemProvider
    {
        public static object GetItem(TaskRunProcessor.Test.Item item)
        {
            return null;
        }

        object IItemProvider.GetItem(Item item)
        {
            return ItemWrapper.GetItem(item);
        }
    }
}
```

If they have to stay static or for any reason you don't have access to the code I would recommend some functional approach:

```
public class GenericProvider : IItemProvider
{
    private Func<Item, object> m_Retriever;

    public GenericProvider(Func<Item,object> retriever)
    {
        if (retriever == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("retriever");
        m_Retriever = retriever;
    }
    object GetItem(Item item)
    {
        return m_Retriever(item);
    }
}
```

Then you sould be able to use `GenericItemProvider' like that:

```
public class ItemProvderClient
{
    public void Use()
    {
        IItemProvider provider1 = new GenericProvider(SomeNamespace.ItemWrapper.GetItem);
        IItemProvider provider2 = new GenericProvider(OtherNamespace.ItemWrapper.GetItem);

        provider1.GetItem(null);
        provider2.GetItem(null);
    }
}
```

In both solution there is no need to create more classes for evey namespace like `SomeNamespaceProvider` class you had in the firs place.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
abstract class ItemWrapper {
    public abstract object GetItem(Item item);
}

class OtherNamespaceItemWrapper : ItemWrapper {
    public override object GetItem(Item item) {
        return OtherNamespace.ItemWrapper.GetItem(item);
    }
}

class SomeNamespaceItemWrapper : ItemWrapper {
    public override object GetItem(Item item) {
        return SomeNamespace.ItemWrapper.GetItem(item);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
class NamespaceProvider<T> where T : ItemWrapper, new() {
    private readonly ItemWrapper itemWrapper;
    public NamespaceProvider() {
        this.itemWrapper = new T();
    }

    public object GetItem(Item item) {
        return this.GetItem(item);
    }
}
```

And:

```
class SomeNamespaceProvider : NamespaceProvider<SomeNamespaceItemWrapper> { }
class OtherNamespaceProvider : NamespaceProvider<OtherNamespaceItemWrapper> { }
```

Comment: This still needs a wrapper class for each namespace am I right?

Comment: If you insist on using static methods like you are doing, yes. Or you can use reflection but that is nasty and smells bad.

Comment: Yes. You will need to create wrappers which inherit from NamespaceProvider<> for every namespace. You end up with many classes. Exatly you will need (namespaces x 2) classes. In my oppinion event the simple class like SomeNamespaceProvider adds complexity to the project.